# Dense Ranking - Looping with for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I was trying to calculate the rank of the given scores for one of my coding challenge but I am kind of struck with the output I received.

I have to create the leaderboard for the given scores (assuming the score is in an `array` in sorted order). I have created a method which gives the rank of the given scores,

```
 private static int[] assignCurrentRanks(int[] scores) {
        int[] currentRanks=new int[scores.length];
        currentRanks[0]=1;//by default the first score will be rank 1
        for(int i=1;i<currentRanks.length;i++) {
            currentRanks[i]=(scores[i]==scores[i-1])?currentRanks[i-1]:++currentRanks[i-1];
            System.out.println("Inside the loop : ["+i+"] "+scores[i]+" "+currentRanks[i]);
        }
        return currentRanks;
 }
```

**Example Input : 100,100,50,40,40,20,10

Expected Rank : 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5**

I could see the rank has been assigned properly during the looping, when I print the rank after in the main method the array returned is different.

I know there is something problem with the logic, but I cannot find it. Please help on this!!

Below is my `main` method,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] scores=new int[]{100,100,50,40,40,20,10};
        int[] currentRanks=assignCurrentRanks(scores);

        System.out.println("Printing after the loop");
        for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++)
            System.out.println("["+i+"]"+scores[i]+" "+currentRanks[i]);
}
```

Result I got is,

```
//index 0 is already assigned with 1 by default
Inside the loop : [1] 100 1
Inside the loop : [2] 50 2
Inside the loop : [3] 40 3
Inside the loop : [4] 40 3
Inside the loop : [5] 20 4
Inside the loop : [6] 10 5
Printing after the loop
[0]100 1
[1]100 2
[2]50 3
[3]40 3
[4]40 4
[5]20 5
[6]10 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++currentRanks[i-1];\\this increments the value of array element i-1`

You increment the rank prior used inside the loop, making unexpected behavior. Should make the expected behavior changing to:

`currentRanks[i]=(scores[i]==scores[i-1])?currentRanks[i-1]:currentRanks[i-1] + 1;`

Comment: Thanks Rafael. So the post increment incremented the value of the element i-1 hence causing this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `++currentRanks[i-1]` is changing the result.

Try this instead:

```
currentRanks[i]=(scores[i]==scores[i-1])?currentRanks[i-1]:currentRanks[i-1]+1;
```